# RealVnc reverse connection to running server--is it possible?

Tags: networking, vnc

Using x11vnc, I can initiate a reverse connection command to a listening vnc client.  It will connect to a vncserver that's already running.  I can't figure out how to do that using RealVnc.

When I use the -connect parameter with vncserver, a new server is started.  But, I want a connection to the vnc server that's shared with several connected vnc clients.

I've used this feature in x11vnc on several rpi projects.   I'm trying to move to RealVnc, but this seems like a showstopper.

Is it possible using RealVnc?

Or, the problem I'm trying to solve--vnc client machines might boot before server.  I want the clients to automatically vnc connect (without user intervention) once server machine boots.

---

I might have a "workaround".  Instead of doing a reverse connection, I'm using ssh to launch a vncviewer on the client platform(s).

But there's another "gotcha"--apparently the vncviewer can't be launched without a password prompt.  I'm using Authentication=VncAuth, but I get an authentication failure, even when explicitly pointing to the vnc password file.

So, I have to use "expect" to provide the password in the vncviewer.

I'm testing to see if there are other issues...

Comment: There's a faint whiff of [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479) here.  Why do you need a machine that presumably has no user at hand to open a remote desktop?  Whatever it is for, there are probably better ways to accomplish it.

Comment: Rpis driving dedicated displays are used in a large venue to show the desktop(s) of a pi running Qt application(s).

Comment: These remote displays should power up and show an assoicated desktop of the pi running vnc server.  They need to boot (and reboot) automatically and attach to server without user intervention.  Closed system, so security not much of a concern.

Comment: This all works (for years) using x11vnc, regardless of which machines are up and running first.    The system of N pis NEVER requires user interaction after initial configuration.

Comment: Trying to workaround not being able to reverse connect to an existing server....  While I can ssh on the server to launch a new viewer on client machines, that assumes the client(s) are already up and running.  In my current implementation, vnc client machines launch xtightvncviewer in listen mode, then issue an ssh to the vnc server to do a reverse connection.  If the server is up, the connection happens immediately.  If it's not up, the connection occurs once the host machine boots and does the reverse connection itself.  Again, the connection needs to be made to an existing server,

Comment: Ok.  Presuming that the RealVNC connections stay up once up but there is no option to call them from the server,  it's probably more worthwhile persuing this the other way around.  Whatever mechanism you're using to boot into a GUI (I think the common one is via auto-login + a DE startup file) should allow you to make it "boot into GUI and try to connect to VNC" and don't stop trying until a connection occurs.

Comment: The vnc server has multiple clients.  The fact that one client isn't up can NOT prevent all the others from working.   

But, I'm actually trying something like this on the client machines.  Keep trying to vncviewer connect until it succeeds.  But, it's not so straight forward, given the need to wrap the vncviewer invocation in expect to provide the password.  But, I think this is the only way (or go back to x11vnc).

Comment: It gets worse.  The client script that loops trying to connect to the vncserver has to keep running even after the connection succeeds.  

The sever may go down, then back up.  So, the script needs to see this and do the connection tries again.   

It's so simple with x11vnc--punting and going back to that.

Comment: I'm asking me what all of this has to do with Raspberry Pi. All RasPis are running, isn't it? And as far as I see RealVnc doesn't miss reverse connections only on RasPis. So it seems to be a problem only for RealVnc.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know.  But, questions about x11vnc issues on Stretch  are typically answered by "use RealVnc it's better anyway".   It would have saved me a couple of days to understand they don't have equivalent functionality and RealVnc is not a superset.   Better to get source and build your own x11Vnc -- the one that's distributed with Raspbian is useless.

Comment: I mean the x11vnc is useless.  It crashes very frequently with the "stack smashing detected" message.

Comment: It would seem easy to point to the fixed version of x11vnc, at least for the apt-get install.  But, instead, I see answers to requests to do this something along the lines of "we won't, because it's not a security issue (and you should use RealVnc--it's better".

Comment: And, to clarify, realVnc does a reverse connection.  But, it starts a new session rather than simply telling a listening client to connect to a specified session.